# Defining a composite primary key in h2

Tags: h2

How can I specify that a table has multiple columns that makeup the primary key? When I run this sql statement, I get "unknown data type "("

```
CREATE TABLE SH_LEAGUE_CONTACT_TEAM_ROLE(ROLE_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
TEAM_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONTACT_ID INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN_KEY(TEAM_ID) REFERENCES SH_LEAGUE_TEAM(ID),
FOREIGN_KEY(CONTACT_ID) REFERENCES SH_LEAGUE_CONTACT(ID),
PRIMARY KEY(ROLE_NAME, TEAM_ID, CONTACT_ID));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in your statement, you have used `FOREIGN_KEY` (one word) instead of `FOREIGN KEY` (two words).